# My app doesn't do the code I've been write Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to understand why my code is not totally played by my application?

In fact I have a button on a viewController when the user press the button two textfield is normal become interactive and the background will change to show the possibility of interaction. When I've do the code and make the first test it work ! It work also in an other view but after some tests the button juste change his hidden property but do nothing else. Cf code :

```
 @IBAction func modifyBtnWasPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //We change the button by the save button

    modifyBtn.isHidden = true
    saveBtn.isHidden = false

    //We enable 2 tf and we show to the user the 2 TF which will be enable

    acftRegistrationTxt.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    acftModelTxt.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    acftRegistrationTxt.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0);
    acftModelTxt.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0);


}
```

Now in this case only the isHidden property work the next 4 lines doesn't apply on the application.

Comment: What is your view background color ? Does it as same as UIColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.9, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0) ?

Comment: bad views connected?

Comment: @Sateesh It's totally white but the `.isUserInteractionEnabled` don't work too ... @sulthan, in this case the button will not change for the other one ?

Comment: Put some breakpoints before and after you change the userInteractionEnabled and see if the textField interaction is effectively enabled by that two lines of code

Comment: @FrancescoDestino nothing happens but the application stop when she cross the breakpoint ...

Comment: Mm that's not okay! When your app is in debug type this on your Xcode terminal "po acftRegistrationTxt.isUserInteractionEnabled" and tell me what you get!
Do the same for acftModelTxt
Type this command when in debug before and after those two lines
acftRegistrationTxt.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
acftModelTxt.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: @FrancescoDestino so for the first line Break Point = False. If I put a BP on the second line I've got True and If I put the BP after the two line is True also !

Comment: So the two textFields are enabled, are you sure that everything is connected good??

Comment: OH guys my bad ! I have been unselected "ENABLE" instead of "ISUSERINTERACTED" on the states on my TF ...

Comment: Ahahahahahha it happens :)